# Loading Static HTML content and adding baseUrl to it, using react-native-webview. returns unexpected url on click

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview.  I am adding static HTML content into it, with baseUrl for relative path.
 {
          console.log(navState);
        }}
      />
on Clicking a link there in Webview,  getting the below log:
{
  canGoForward: false, 
  canGoBack: false, 
  title: "", 
  loading: true, 
  url: "data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,", …}

How to get the exact url? I'm trying this on Android Emulator

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're referring to `navState` object of the `onNavigationStateChange` function when you did the following:

`onNavigationStateChange={navState => { //some logic }}`

The `navState` object includes these properties:

```
canGoBack
canGoForward
loading
navigationType
target
title
url
```

In fact, you console logged the `navState` object.

To get the URL, use `navState.url`. Hence `console.log(navState.url)` would log the URL.

Note: This method will not be invoked on hash URL changes. [See this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange).

Comment: Thank Vighnesh for answering. There was issue with my "baseUrl" as the right url was not being passed was causing the issue. It is fixed now by correcting the baseUrl.